# addToCart Event is triggered only first time for each product

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager

I'm facing a situation where the addToCart is fired only the first time someone click add to cart button, after that if you try to add the same product - even changing quantity or color or size - doesn't fire the addToCart event. Any other product is added.

I've create an observer that creates the coookie addToCart withj the required data but still no luck.

Observer is hooked to this event:

> checkout_cart_add_product_complete

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: are there any errors in <magento2 folder>/var/log/exception.log ? search for the event code maybe or the observer file name

Comment: Hi @Rustyjim no errors regarding event or observer. Only error is :report.CRITICAL: The element "category.product.type.details.renderers" can't have a child because "category.product.type.details.renderers" already has a child with alias "configurable". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"category.product.type.details.renderers\" can't have a child because \"category.product.type.details.renderers\" already has a child with alias \"configurable\". at /app/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []

Comment: and if u try another one like checkout_cart_product_add_after? it is fired later i believe :)

Comment: @Rustyjim nothing. I just noticed that if you don't change properties and add the same product then addToCart event is fired and cart is updated. If you change propertie eg size or color, addToCart ain't fired but cart is updated. Also removeFromCart is working fine